# What are the consequences of using unity tweak tools on elementary

Tags: release-freya, tweak-tool

What will happen if I use unity tweak tool in elementary OS? Does it break my system?

*Please explain in detail.*

Comment: OK, so is there a way to change font size of particular UI elements (i. e. windows title bar, menus, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you what will happen. Probably you will be able to install it but it won't change anything since elementary OS uses the Pantheon desktop and not Unity.

In case you want a similar app for elementary OS, there's one called [elementary tweaks](https://launchpad.net/elementary-tweaks).

To install it you just need to:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```

Beware that you are adding a PPA, this PPA didn't cause me any problems but you never know, be careful when you add a new one.
Also, this project is not maintained right now so it may stop working on future releases of elementary OS.